# Spring Boot and React: Access to XMLHttpRequest at X has been blocked by CORS

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios, cors, microservices

I'm getting this error whenever I send a request from my React App to my Spring Boot backend.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8082/customermanagement%E2%80%8B/api%E2%80%8B/services%E2%80%8B/prospect%E2%80%8B/[object%20Object]%E2%80%8B/delete' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I'm leaving the code below.

#### Spring Boot Backend

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST)
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

**ProspectController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(MICROSERVICE_SERVICES_PROSPECT_PREFIX)
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class ProspectController {

@Autowired
private ProspectService prospectService;

@DeleteMapping("/{prospectId}/delete")
public ResponseEntity<ProspectResponse> delete(@PathVariable("prospectId") Integer prospectId) {
    ProspectResponse response = prospectService.delete(prospectId);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**React code**

```
let handleDelete = async (id) => {
        console.log(id)
    await axios.delete("http://localhost:8082/customermanagement​/api​/services​/prospect​/" + {id} + "​/delete")
    .then(() => console.log('Delete successful'));
}
```

Could you help me with this problem?

I think that there could be a problem with my Spring Security Config.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try changing the order, something like this:

```
httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).authenticated()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
```

the order in which the "authorize" is written matters!